# MVC 6 asp-validation-summary omits property name for validation on hidden input

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following markup in my `Create` view for model `EmployeeBindingModel`:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
<input type="hidden" asp-for="EmployeeId" />
```

If I leave the stupid scaffolded `Create` action as is, it passes a null model to the view, despite the controller being typed for `EmployeeBindingModel`. Then on submit, the client side validation doesn't work at all, but that is the subject of another question.

This question is why does the controller's model validation only return the following message, without a property name, for `EmployeeId`?

```
The value '' is invalid.
```

Comment: And why is `The` styled as blue in the SO rendering of that code?

Comment: Client side validation doesn't work with hidden fields by default. JQuery the default settings says ignore: ":hidden".

Comment: @MaxMokrousov Why not try make that an answer, and maybe suggest how to change the "ignore hidden" default in question? I would be very open to accepting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client side jQuery validation has default value to [ignore hidden fields.](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#ignore)

> ignore (default: ":hidden") Type: Selector. Elements to ignore when validating, simply filtering them out. jQuery's not-method is used, therefore everything that is accepted by not() can be passed as this option. Inputs of type submit and reset are always ignored, so are disabled elements

To fix it you can override.

```
@section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $.validator.setDefaults({
             ignore: ""
        });
      </script>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this could be quite useful. Although, as is, your code will ignore all but `submit` and `reset` elements. Although the ignore value is a selector, so I can use classes to be more selective.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to provide a name for it to be picked up by the Controller.

```
<input type="hidden" name="EmployeeId" asp-for="EmployeeId" />
```

If you wish to use Razor, you could use the following:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
```

Comment: I have used Razor, the modern version, i.e. MVC 6, ASP.NET Core, where `<input type="hidden" asp-for="EmployeeId" />` means exactly the same as `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmployeeId)`.

Comment: Ah I see, apologies. Didn't know this.

Comment: Get with the times, Kris. :-) The jewel that is MVC Core makes MVC 5 look like a ball of dung. It's all free and open source, even the required IDE's are free.